# Rails 4 low-level caching not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I think is not working because I test it with a real db situation, and always returns the content of db

1. Execute the `Rails.cache.fetch`
2. Modify the database
3. Execute again the `Rails.cache.fetch`, and here It **not** should return the new value that I've modified in db. but it happens, not caching is executed

   class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base

   ```
   def self.translate(es_text,locale=I18n.locale)

     Rails.cache.fetch("#{es_text}/#{locale}", expires_in: 1.month) do
       trad=self.find_by_es_text(es_text)
       translated=eval("trad.#{locale}_text")
       return translated if translated.present?
     end

   end
   ```

   end

The test:

I Execute `Translation.translate('Alojamiento','en')` and it returns what finds on DB : `"Accomodation"`

Then I modify the database table replacing "Accomodation" with "Accomodation---", and commit,...

Come back to Rails, execute the same `Translation.translate('Alojamiento','en')` and it returns the new value `"Accomodation---"` !!!

**But it shouldn't!! isn't it?** Because I have put `expires_in: 1.month` not in `1.second`

Or, Does Rails know when database is modified, and expire cache automatically?

I think the cache is not working, or maybe I'm missing some configuration

Thanks a lot

---

- One way to make "it works" (but I don't like) is moving the `Rails.cache...` code in a method controller, and call a url like `www.app/translate/Alojamiento?locale=en`. 
  In this case it works, but caching in a model is more correct.

  ```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...  
    def translate
      text_return=Rails.cache.fetch("#{params[:es_text]}/#{params[:locale]}", expires_in: 1.month) do
        Translation.translate(params[:es_text],params[:locale])
      end
      render text: text_to_return
    end
  ```

Comment: are you seeing this in your development environment?  Make sure that `config/environments/development.rb` doesn't have `config.cache_store = :null_store` which would disable caching.

Comment: No, in production environment, in two diferent servers (local, through rails s -e producion. And Apache production server).

Comment: I think Rails.cache.fetch has something that makes it different, if it is executing in Model or in Controller

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in put the cache result in a variable, and return it

IT seems is not the same, this:

```
def self.translate(es_text,locale=I18n.locale)
  retorn_text=Rails.cache.fetch("#{es_text}/#{locale}", expires_in: 1.month) do
    trad=self.find_by_es_text(es_text)

    eval("trad.#{locale}_text")
  end

  retorn_text 
end
```

than this:

```
def self.translate(es_text,locale=I18n.locale)
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{es_text}/#{locale}", expires_in: 1.month) do
    trad=self.find_by_es_text(es_text)

    eval("trad.#{locale}_text")
  end
end
```

But I don't understand why

Comment: Caching the result of an email validation, I see this, too. Storing it in the local variable 'retorn_text' was sufficient, the 'translated' variable was not needed. Rails 6, ruby 2.7.1