# Rails low level caching is not working for active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis, graphql

I'm using `graphql` for my rails api. And use `redis` for cache store.

In a graphql query, I'm using cache to optimize performance:

**graphql/types/query_type.rb**

```rb
field :labels, [Types::LabelType], null: false do
  description 'Get all food labels'
end

def labels
  Rails.cache.fetch("labels", expires_in: 24.hours) do
    Label.all
  end
end
```

10 labels are seeded in the database and when I test query in `localhost:3000/graphiql`, it shows 10 results correctly. However, if I delete a row manually in the database, it returns 9 records instead of cached 10 results.

Here is my environment configuration:

**config/environments/development.rb**

```rb
if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL_CACHING", "redis://localhost:6379/0") }
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

I ran `rails dev:cache` and there is `caching-dev.txt` in `tmp` directory.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you mean `rails dev:cache`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for typo.

Comment: I think my answer on this question about [Model Fragment Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954529/rails-5-2-1-model-fragment-caching/51955308#51955308) may have some relevance here. (not sure if the question itself is close enough as a duplicate and that asker said the answer didn't help them, but I feel like it may be what I thought was their issue)

Comment: @SimpleLime Hi, thank you for your attention. I came up with a solution but I don't guess the reason behind. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar questions and tried their answers. 
Suggested solutions are:

- Load models: `Label.all.load` ([Rails 5.2.1 - Model & Fragment Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954529/rails-5-2-1-model-fragment-caching/51955308#51955308))
- Convert them to arrays: `Label.to_a` ([Low level caching in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390836/low-level-caching-in-rails-4))
- Store the result to a local variable: `labels = Label.all` ([Rails 4 low-level caching not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739267/rails-4-low-level-caching-not-working))

The first and second work correctly.

**graphql/types/query_type.rb**

```rb
def labels
  Rails.cache.fetch("labels", expires_in: 24.hours) do
    Label.all.load
  end
end
```

## Tips: Run `Rails.cache.clear` in rails console whenever you change the cache block

The problem was that it is the block `Label.all` that was cached, not the results.

No matter how I change the block, it is already cached, so the results are **NOT** cached.

I ran `Rails cache clear` in rails console and it worked correctly.